# Isabelle: What if a session needs more than one parent session?

Tags: isabelle

I have developed a set of theories that uses both Eisbach and the HOL Library. Everything works fine inside Isabelle/jEdit. However, when trying to build the corresponding session with `isabelle build`, both Eisbach and the HOL Library aren’t found. In the past, when I didn’t yet need the HOL Library, I fixed this by specifying `HOL-Eisbach` instead of `HOL` as the parent session in the `ROOT` file. With the need for the HOL Library, this trick doesn’t work anymore, as you cannot have more than one parent session.

How can I build a session that uses Eisbach and the HOL Library at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify additional sessions that your session depends on in the `sessions` block of your ROOT file, e.g. (example taken from the AFP):

```
session Zeta_Function (AFP) = Dirichlet_Series +
  options [timeout = 600]
  sessions
    Euler_MacLaurin
    Bernoulli
  theories [document = false]
    "Dirichlet_Series.Dirichlet_Series_Analysis"
  theories
    Zeta_Function
  document_files
    "root.tex"
```

This session has `Dirichlet_Series` as a parent session and additionally depends on the sessions `Euler_MacLaurin` and `Bernoulli`.

So how do you decide which of your dependencies should be the parent session? Well, keep in mind that in order to build your session, the parent session has to be built first, but as soon as the parent session is available, you can just use it without further cost. This is why we let things depend on `HOL` by default: it is typically available pre-built.

It also means that it does not make much sense to choose a session as your parent if you only use a small part of it. This is why I avoid choosing `HOL-Library` as a parent session. Usually, one only needs one or two theories from it, which can easily be processed within a few seconds, but if you choose it as your parent, a user has to build *all* of `HOL-Library` in order to use your session.

So, I would say you should choose the parent like this:

- Make a list of all the sessions that you depend on and from which you use a significant amount of material
- Choose the biggest session on that list as a parent

If the parent you end up with is very small (e.g. `HOL-Eisbach`), you don't actually gain much from choosing it as the parent. You can do so, but you can also choose `HOL`.

Comment: I think you can remove the `theories [document = false]` block. Imports from other sessions do not appear in the document by default.

Comment: You may be right about that; I suspected something similar, but  there were some odd cases where this didn't work as expected.